# Aspnet identity: manage users using a generic class

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-identity

I have defined 3 classes that inherit from IdentityUser since I want to store different properties for each type of user but have the common ones in one class.
My question is how can i have a generic usermanager class that loads the correct membership type
A simple example

```
public class MembershipUser : IdentityUser
{
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class Membership1 : MembershipUser
{
    public int? Level_ID { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}

public class Membership2 : MembershipUser
{
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I want to have a generic usermanager class 
like this

```
public class UserManager<T> : UserManager<T>  where T: IUser
{
public UserManager()
                : base(new UserStore<T>(new MembershipManagementContext()))
{
}
```

but i get an error "Error   1   'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments"

Comment: You're inheriting from yourself. class UserManager<T> : UserManager<T>

Comment: doh! thnx. if you had it as an answer i would have marked it as accepted

Answer (score 0):

In order to use generics UserManager** the classes you want to use have to have a parameterless constructor. So forexample the MembershipUser must contain:

```
public MembershipUser()
{
  // Initialization
}
```

Comment: but it says a constructor with 1 argument?!.